# Showing a bootstrap alert message for a specific time in html and css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have this element below that shows a success/failure banner across the screen.
Is there a way I can set it in html/css to hide after 4 seconds?

```html
<div id=mainAlertMessage class="alert @message.CssClassName alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <div style="text-align: center"><strong>@message.Title</strong> @message.Message</div>
</div>
```

I'm showing it by setting tempData in my controllers like this

```
TempData["UserMessage"] = new BannerMessage() { CssClassName = "alert-success", Title = "Success!", Message = "Notification settings were updated!" };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript `setTimeout` function on document ready event. Assuming you have jQuery included in the page,

```
$(function () { 
    var duration = 4000; // 4 seconds
    setTimeout(function () { $('#mainAlertMessage').hide(); }, duration);
});
```

You do not necessarily need jquery for this, With vanilla javascript, you wire up the code in `onload` event

```
window.onload = function() {
    var duration = 2000; //2 seconds
    setTimeout(function () { $('#mainAlertMessage').hide(); }, duration);
};
```

Comment: This doesn't deserve a downvote. @shyju clearly states it is *not* possible without JS and has provided the alternative

Comment: well, then is it possible to inline the js in the html? It's not the question I originally asked

Comment: What you mean inline js in the html. You can include that js code i have in the answer inside a script tag in your page.

Comment: You can create a function which is fired inline?
`<button onclick="myFunction()"></button>`And then define your `setTimeout` elsewhere, but that's as close as you'll get. Also, you should accept the answer given.

Comment: Yes. You can put the `setTimeout` call inside your `myFunction` definition and can be invoked in a button click

Comment: I'd like to do something like onLoad, but it doesn't look like onload is supported with div tags

Comment: You should do it on the  `window.load`. You are rendering the div and message when razor execute this view. So once it is rendered you can hide it after 5 seconds ?

Comment: Take a look at @Bram G's answer. It is possible with CSS `@keyframes` as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS animation and keyframes to accomplish your desired result.

```css
    .alert {
        animation: autoHide 0s ease-in 4s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes autoHide {
        to {
            width:0;
            height:0;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
```

```html
<div id=mainAlertMessage class="alert @message.CssClassName alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <div style="text-align: center"><strong>@message.Title</strong> @message.Message</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No worries, CSS came a long way.

Comment: Wow I also never for a sec thought of using keyframes. Great answer @BramG